# exclude all hidden files and directories in solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, find, hidden

Unix newbie could use your help.

I'm using Solaris 10 and need to find all files, excluding all hidden files and directories.  The ultimate goal is to put this in a script that will delete files 60+ days old on a server.

I tried:

find . ! ( -name '.*' -prune )

but it finds no files at all.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are excluding everything named ".*", and you are starting your search at "." (which matches your exclusion), so you are excluding everything.  Also, I believe you are misusing the `-prune` flag (it's an action, like `-print`, and so isn't necessarily useful as part of a negated expression).  Try this:

```
find . \( -name '.*' \! -name '.' -prune \) -o -print
```

This explicitly includes '.' in the search, and then excludes everything else matching `.*`.  If you know that your starting point doesn't include any dotfiles, you can simplify this a bit:

```
find * \( -name '.*' -prune \) -o -print
```

Comment: larsks, thanks for your response.  yes this does indeed work.  i'm also curious, since i also need to delete the files, is the following syntax correct:  find . \( -name '.*' \! -name '.' -prune \) -o -exec rm -f {} \

Comment: That is, although note that for a large number of files, it's generally better to pipe the output of find to "xargs rm".  E.g., something like "find ... -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f" (the -0 tells find (and xargs) to null-terminate, instead of whitespace-terminate, filenames, which is important if your filesystem has filenames that contain spaces).  Also, if this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 For versions of `find` that support it, you can get the performance provided by `xargs` (without using it) by using `+` to terminate the `-exec` portion of `find` instead of `\;`.

Comment: dennis, solaris does not accept "xargs -0" so i will explore your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
find * | grep -v /\\.
```

Comment: jlliagre, thanks for your response.  while it does work, i don't believe it will let me remove those files.  that is, i need to tack on a "-exec rm -f {} \" (without quotes).  please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: If your directories and files have "regular" names, i.e. no embedded spaces or similar, you might use this: "find * -mtime +60 -type f | grep -v /\\. | xargs rm -f" . However, a find only command like the one suggested by larsks is more robust as it will properly handle odd names.

Comment: If you are okay using GNU grep (and find and xargs?), you can use: "find * -mtime +60 -type f -print0 | grep -zZv /\\. | xargs -0 rm -f" (not sure if the -Z option to grep is necessary; I think it isn't)

Comment: You need also gnu find and gnu xargs for this to work. These utilities are generally not all available on Solaris 10. They are with OpenSolaris/Solaris 11 though. The only advantage of my solution was it was shorter and simpler to understand than the "-prune" one. That is probably not the case anymore with this convoluted Gnuish one ...

Answer (score 0):

> need to find all files
>   excluding all hidden (files and directories).

find . -name '[^.]*'

> excluding all (hidden files) and directories.

find . -type f -name '[^.]*'

> The ultimate goal is to put this in a script that will delete files 60+ days old on a server

find . -name '[^.]*' -mtime +59 | xargs rm -f

Comment: eduardo, unfortunately this doesn't work in solaris.  it returns no files.  however i haven't tried this on linux.  thanks.

Comment: This kind of works with Gnu find, however, non hidden files located in hidden directories are detected. This is probably not what hsw is looking for.